# Reguler Expresion in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this text:

```
DIAGNOSIS
M19.072 Primary osteoarthritis, left ankle and foot 1
M19.072 Primary osteoarthritis, left ankle and foot 2
O   RTHOSIS DEVICE(S) PRESCRIBED

gfgfgfggfgfg
111111111112ffffffffff
gfggggg

DIAGNOSIS
M17.12 Unilateral primary osteoarthritis, left knee
O   RTHOSIS DEVICE(S) PRESCRIBED

gfgfgfggfgfg
11111ttttfffff

gffffffffffffffffffffffffwwwwwwwwwree


DIAGNOSIS
M75.42 Impingement syndrome of left shoulder
O   RTHOSIS DEVICE(S) PRESCRIBED

gfgfgfggfgfg
111111111112ffffffffff

gfggggg
wwwwwwwwww
```

and i want to get only this three lines !!!!

```
M19.072 Primary osteoarthritis, left ankle and foot 1
M19.072 Primary osteoarthritis, left ankle and foot 2
M17.12 Unilateral primary osteoarthritis, left knee
M75.42 Impingement syndrome of left shoulder
```

this is my python code but didnt work sometimes!

```
diagnosis_Answer = re.findall(r"(DIAGNOSIS(\s.*?)+RTHOSIS DEVICE)+", txt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
DIAGNOSIS((?:\n.*)*?)\n.*RTHOSIS DEVICE
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MWkiqw/3). **Details**:

- `DIAGNOSIS\n` - `DIAGNOSIS` and a newline
- `((?:\n.*)*?)` - Group 1: zero or more (but as few as possible) occurrences of a newline and then any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\n` - a newline
- `.*RTHOSIS DEVICE` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible and then `RTHOSIS DEVICE` string.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/zUouch):

```
import re
txt = 'DIAGNOSIS\nM19.072 Primary osteoarthritis, left ankle and foot 1\nM19.072 Primary osteoarthritis, left ankle and foot 2\nO   RTHOSIS DEVICE(S) PRESCRIBED\n\ngfgfgfggfgfg\n111111111112ffffffffff\ngfggggg\nwwwwwwwwww\n\nDIAGNOSIS\nM17.12 Unilateral primary osteoarthritis, left knee\nO   RTHOSIS DEVICE(S) PRESCRIBED\n\n\ngfgfgfggfgfg\n11111ttttfffff\ngffffffffffffffffffffffffwwwwwwwwwree\n\nDIAGNOSIS\nM75.42 Impingement syndrome of left shoulder\nO   RTHOSIS DEVICE(S) PRESCRIBED\n\n\ngfgfgfggfgfg\n111111111112ffffffffff\ngfggggg\nwwwwwwwwww\n'
diagnosis_Answer = []
matches = re.findall(r"DIAGNOSIS((?:\n.*)*?)\n.*RTHOSIS DEVICE", txt)
for m in matches:
    diagnosis_Answer.extend(m.strip().splitlines())
print(diagnosis_Answer)
```

Output:

```
['M19.072 Primary osteoarthritis, left ankle and foot 1', 'M19.072 Primary osteoarthritis, left ankle and foot 2', 'M17.12 Unilateral primary osteoarthritis, left knee', 'M75.42 Impingement syndrome of left shoulder']
```

Comment: plz chech the text again , because the result  its may have more than one line

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you just take the lines with the good beginning `M\d{2}\.\d+.*`, the `M` and the digits

```
diagnosis_Answer = re.findall(r"M\d{2}\.\d+.*", text)
```

---

If you want to fiw your idea, to match `DIAGNOSIS` before and `RTHOSIS` after, you need to add the break-line char `DIAGNOSIS\n+(.*)\n+.*RTHOSIS DEVICE`

```
diagnosis_Answer = re.findall(r"DIAGNOSIS\n+(.*)\n+.*RTHOSIS DEVICE", text)
```

---

[`OnlineDemo`](https://repl.it/repls/FavorableTriangularRange)

Comment: @AyoubRastan  like which lines ? For me the first regex just match the 4 lines starting with M...

Comment: can u edit the first regex and add  "DIAGNOSIS and RTHOSIS DEVICE" to match exactly what i want ?

Comment: @AyoubRasta if you tell what content that you don't want is returned by the first one actually

Comment: thatnk you bro the above answer helped me,      re.findall(r"DIAGNOSIS((?:\n.*)*?)\n.*RTHOSIS DEVICE", txt)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the below regex. You can try to watch the regex live in action at this [link](https://regex101.com/r/mU6eMr/1/).

```
DIAGNOSIS\n+?(.*)\n+?.*RTHOSIS DEVICE
```

The above regex would take care of all the newlines in between.

Now this would match the entire string. What you might be interested in would be the groups!
So checkout this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-groups-method-in-regular-expressions-in-Python) which talks heavily about groups in python RE.

Comment: plz chech the text again , because the result  its may have more than one line